# How to get the build stage name in Travis-CI?

Tags: bash, travis-ci

I am using the Travis-CI build stages and [this discord webhook](https://github.com/k3rn31p4nic/travis-ci-discord-webhook/blob/master/send.sh) for a personal project. Everything works as expected; I show a notification on my discord every time a build stage finishes.

However, I want to get the build stage name to display it on discord, but there are no [default environment variables](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Default-Environment-Variables) for the stage names.

I am aware that there is an [open feature request](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/8239) on the Travis GitHub for the build stage name environment variables, however I wanted to know if there is a work around to get the build stage name.